# maven:: mvn clean install: stucks at repository dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a springboot project. I am trying to install the dependencies but it gets stuck

```
simha@55afc69c496d:~/app$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from redshift: https://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
```

Any idea.

the below is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-data-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-data-backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.platform.version>1.2.0</junit.platform.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>sm-analytics</docker.image.prefix>
        <querydsl.version>4.2.1</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.543</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Querydsl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iam</artifactId>
          </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.rollbar</groupId>
               <artifactId>rollbar-java</artifactId>
               <version>1.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>https://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                          <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                          </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
                                <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and the dockerfile used to build and run the above project is

```
# Maven Image
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN
WORKDIR /code

ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml

ADD src /code/src

CMD [ "mvn", "spring-boot:run" ]
```

Comment: can you share your pom too ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I have edited the question and put the pom file and docker container.

Comment: Does the redshift repository require username and password? If so, you need it configured e.g. in your `.m2/settings.xml` file, such as `<server><id>redshift</id><username>username</username><password>password</password></server>`

Comment: I dont think so. If see the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc20-connection-with-maven.html

Comment: I can still think of a few steps. It's weird that it tries to download Spring Boot from redshift. 1. Check if you didn't somehow suppressed Maven central. Open your **effective pom** (not your own pom!) and check if there is something like`<repository>...<id>central</id>...<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url></repository>`
2. Go to your local repository and delete the whole `.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot` folder. Sometimes there might be stuck partially loaded artifacts.

Comment: Hi I am using the docker image which i have show above. So can you try that